# Exporting ArcGIS Online Map as PDF and Layer with GPS Coordinates Not Showing Up

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I created the following map (which consists of two layers) on ArcGIS Online, and I am trying to save it as a PDF. See below for the map:

[image: ArcGIS Map]

However, when I try to print or save the above map as a PDF, the pins do not appear on the map. See below:

[image: PDF of Map - No GPS Coordinates]

Is there a reason why the GPS coordinates are not coming out in the PDF printout?

Comment: Your tag says ArcGIS Desktop but your first screenshot looks like an ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Portal web map. Are you trying to print from the web map? Also, your legend only shows one layer. Is the GPS points a layer in your web map and turned on when you attempt to print?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is indeed ArcGIS Online. There did not seem to be a tag for it. Also, the GPS points are indeed a layer uploaded as an .xml file. There doesn't seem to be an option to activate them during the print out. Is there a reason why? @Tigerwoulds

Comment: How did you upload your GPS points? If you uploaded them inside the webmap viewer then the print service does not have access to the data. In order for the print service to work you would have to upload the data as an e.g. AGOL feature service.

Comment: Hi @Carlos, many thanks for your help. I believe I did the former. I uploaded the GPS coordinates as a layer. Is there a way to upload the coordinates as an AGOL feature service?

Comment: You will need an AGOL account with the required permissions. See the following link on how to add data through the browser:https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/add-items.htm .There is also a way to upload data through ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro; you do need a license again though.